# Go to URL with ID onClick() Using Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am building a simple contact database with Laravel and a MySQL database. I have a basic HTML file with a data table that list a series of records. I would like to make it so that when I click on a row, I go to a page based on the ID number of the record in the row clicked.

I have the table populated using a @foreach loop as such:

```
<tbody>
                @foreach ($people as $person)

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a>{!! link_to_action('ContactController@show', $person->id, $person->id) !!}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ $person->name_first }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $person->name_middle }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $person->name_last }}</td>
                    </tr>

                @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

The controller (ContactController) shows this:

```
public function show($id)
    {

        $person = Contact::findOrFail($id);

        return view('contacts.show', compact('person'));

    }
```

Now, I have a JavaScript script on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contacts').dataTable();

    $('#contacts tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var name = $('td', this).eq(1).text();
        alert( 'You clicked on '+name+'\'s row' );
        window.location="";
    } );
} );

</script>
```

I assume I only need to insert the proper link in:

```
window.location="";
```

How do I write the link? I tried writing a number of variations with the Laravel syntax, where I need to access a route in my ContactController that would go to contacts/{id}. I tried:

```
window.location="{{URL::to('contacts', $person->id)}}";
```

That doesn't work. Please let me know what link to use in order to go to contacts/1 or contacts2, for example.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$('#contacts tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var name = $('td', this).eq(1).text();
    var link = $('td', this).eq(0).find('a');
    alert('You clicked on ' + name + '\'s row');
    window.location=link.attr('href');
});
```

And the show method only accepts one argument.

```
<td>
  {!! link_to_action('ContactController@show', $person->id) !!}
</td>
```

And no need to wrap it in "a" tags

Comment: That link works in the table which is set up as a @foreach. However, then I use as you suggested, it links to the last is in the table (such as contact/17) and not the id of the table row selected (such as contact/{id}) .

Comment: Can you post your foreach loop and your Show method on your ContactController.

Comment: I updated the question to include my show method in ContactController and the foreach loop in my HTML to generate the table.

Comment: I guess what I am missing is how to use jQuery to find the id for the row that is clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Add your link to a data attribute on your `tr` element and then use it in your JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($people as $person)
    <tr data-link='{{ action('ContactController@show', $person->id) }}'>
        <td>
            <a>{!! link_to_action('ContactController@show', $person->id, $person->id) !!}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ $person->name_first }}</td>
        <td>{{ $person->name_middle }}</td>
        <td>{{ $person->name_last }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#contacts tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var name = $('td', this).eq(1).text();
    alert( 'You clicked on '+name+'\'s row' );
    window.location = this.getAttribute('data-link');
} );
```